# Filter Babelnet synsets by category

Tags: java, nlp, wsd

I'm using Babelnet java api to query the online service:

**1)** I get the synset of some words by the babelnet relation `.getSynsets()` on a babelnet instance

**2)** I also have a method to get the categories of these words by the relation `.getDomains()`.

I want to get the synsets but only those related to a specific domain, for example the word "apple" generates the synsets: {Apple (music group), Apple, Ariane Passenger PayLoad Experiment, Apple (album)} and domains :{MUSIC, COMPUTING, PHYSICS AND ASTRONOMY}.

Specifying the MUSIC domain I want to end up with the synset {Apple (music group), Apple (album)}, so: is there any way to filter the synset I get on step **1)** by any specific domain got through step **2)**?

Comment: Looks like there is no such method like `getSynsets(String word, BabelDomain domain)`. 
Unfortunately, only iterating over the `List<BabelSynset>` result from `getSynsets(...)` will achieve your goal.